# Loop through string with non-standard EOL delimiter

Tags: bash

I'm trying to loop on the output of a command which spits out lines delimited with \n instead of the bash internal field separator. I have a workaround which temporarily changes the IFS to \n:

```
timestamps=$(somefortranprogram someinputfile)
OIFS="${IFS}"
NIFS=$'\n'
IFS="${NIFS}"
for timestamp in $timestamps
do
    IFS="${OIFS}"
    <things to do in loop>
    IFS="${NIFS}"
done
```

The output from the fortran program is in the form:

```
June 27, 1989 00 UTC (+ 00 Hrs)
June 27, 1989 03 UTC (+ 00 Hrs)
June 27, 1989 06 UTC (+ 00 Hrs)
June 27, 1989 09 UTC (+ 00 Hrs)
June 27, 1989 12 UTC (+ 00 Hrs)
June 27, 1989 15 UTC (+ 00 Hrs)
June 27, 1989 18 UTC (+ 00 Hrs)
```

...which would work fine to loop timestamp over each line, except that bash loops over whitespace and thus runs through each word.
Is there a better way to do this which doesn't involve temporarily changing $IFS?

Answer (score 1):

[The normal way to read line by line is with a while-read loop.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line
do
  echo "$line"
done < <(somecommand)
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion, though each iteration will inevitably be printing out a number of lines (I'm doing a number of things which print inside of the loop), so once the end of the list is reached it seems like it will keep going...

Comment: @Stochtastic: It won't, because the `while` loop will be reading the output of `somecommand`, not of itself.

Answer (score 0):

I like this way better, using a bash array. It still changes the IFS though, but only for creating the array.

```
OIFS="${IFS}"
IFS=$'\n'
timestamps=($(somefortranprogram someinputfile))
IFS="${OIFS}"

for timestamp in "${timestamps[@]}"; do
    <things to do in loop>
done
```

If there are very many of the lines, however, I believe Ignacio's suggestion to work as a filter on the output would perform much better.